# uWSGI spawning too many threads

Tags: python, uwsgi, systemd

Similar to [uwsgi spawning more processes than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162097/uwsgi-spawning-more-processes-than-expected) but since that one is unanswered and I don't have enough reputation to ask there, spinning this up again. This ([UWSGI killing workers too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307401/uwsgi-killing-workers-too-fast)) might be relevant, too.

---

My situation: I have a flask application, uWSGI and nginx. The non-systemd execution of my uWSGI configuration works as a charm. When I launch uWSGI using emperor I see one process running. When I add a `.ini` file to the vassals location, the thing explodes, launching and killing processes so fast that the CPU goes up to 100% usage and the VM I'm working on collapses. It doesn't seem to matter what the content of the `.ini` file is (have tried an empty one).

---

/some/nfs/share/workers/conf

```
PYTHONPATH=/some/nfs/share/production/repo
PATH=/some/nfs/share/production/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
UWSGI_BIN=/some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi
UWSGI_INI=/some/nfs/share/workers/emperor.ini
```

emperor.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=mygroup

EnvironmentFile=/some/nfs/share/workers/conf

ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${UWSGI_BIN} --ini ${UWSGI_INI}'

RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi

RestartSec=5
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

emperor.ini

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /some/nfs/share/uwsgi/

uid = myuser
gid = mygroup
```

the actual service `.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = /some/nfs/share/production/repo/app/main.py
callable = create_app

# load some variables
for-readline = /some/nfs/share/workers/conf
  env = %(_)
endfor =

plugins = python

wsgi-disable-file-wrapper = true

socket = /some/nfs/share/workers/uwsgi/%n.sock
pidfile = /some/nfs/share/workers/uwsgi/%n.pid

chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
close-on-exec = true
```

another dummy service `.ini` file I tried, that causes the same problem (yes, it's empty):

```
[uwsgi]
```

---

If I add logging to the emepror.ini, I get:

emperor.ini

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /some/nfs/share/uwsgi/

uid = myuser
gid = evfold

logger = file:/some/nfs/share/uwsgi/emperor.log
```

In turn, this will spawn two processes instead of one:

```
● emperor.service - uWSGI Emperor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/emperor.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-07-05 11:09:40 EDT; 2min 7s ago
 Main PID: 19777 (uwsgi)
   Status: "The Emperor is governing 0 vassals"
   CGroup: /system.slice/emperor.service
           ├─19777 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini /some/nfs/share/workers/emperor.ini
           └─19778 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini /some/nfs/share/workers/emperor.ini

Jul 05 11:09:40 backend systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI Emperor...
Jul 05 11:09:40 backend sh[19777]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /some/nfs/share/workers/emperor.ini
Jul 05 11:09:40 backend sh[19777]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /some/nfs/share/workers/emperor.ini
Jul 05 11:09:40 backend systemd[1]: Started uWSGI Emperor.
```

this the log file until now (notice that everything is duplicated, most likely because the logger instance is separate:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.16 (64bit) on [Thu Jul  5 11:09:40 2018] ***
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.16 (64bit) on [Thu Jul  5 11:09:40 2018] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) on 12 February 2018 22:16:17
compiled with version: 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) on 12 February 2018 22:16:17
os: Linux-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 9 14:09:15 UTC 2015
os: Linux-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 9 14:09:15 UTC 2015
nodename: backend
nodename: backend
machine: x86_64
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /
current working directory: /
detected binary path: /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi
detected binary path: /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi
dropping root privileges as early as possible
dropping root privileges as early as possible
your processes number limit is 31212
your processes number limit is 31212
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
dropping root privileges after socket binding
dropping root privileges after socket binding
Python version: 3.5.4 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Aug 14 2017, 13:26:58)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
Python version: 3.5.4 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Aug 14 2017, 13:26:58)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1cf2180
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1cf2180
dropping root privileges after plugin initialization
dropping root privileges after plugin initialization
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
*** Operational MODE: no-workers ***
*** Operational MODE: no-workers ***
dropping root privileges after application loading
dropping root privileges after application loading
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 19777)
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 19777)
```

if I then add the `production.ini` in the vassals folder, I get the following log:

```
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 10) ***
*** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 10) ***
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /some/nfs/share/workers/emperor.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /some/nfs/share/workers/emperor.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from production.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from production.ini
open("./python_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3713]
open("./python_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3713]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
Thu Jul  5 11:22:29 2018 - [emperor] vassal production.ini is now loyal
Thu Jul  5 11:22:29 2018 - [emperor] vassal production.ini is now loyal
```

the `python_plugin` error doesn't seem to affect execution in any particular way, I can remove the `plugins = python` from the `.ini` file and that wouldn't change much.

At this stage, there are 50+ workers associated to the uWSGI workers above and the machine becomes completely unresponsive.

Any help is appreciated :)

---

**EDIT**: I was able to isolate the emperor.service once, without logging and with the production.ini file in the vassals it looks like this (I assume, instead, that the vessels should be nested inside the main PID over there?)

```
● emperor.service - uWSGI Emperor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/emperor.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-07-05 12:01:57 EDT; 12min ago
 Main PID: 25432 (uwsgi)
   Status: "The Emperor is governing 1 vassals"
   CGroup: /system.slice/emperor.service
           ├─25432 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini /some/nfs/share/workers/emperor.ini
           ├─25960 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25961 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25962 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25963 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25964 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25965 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25966 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25967 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25968 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25969 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25970 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25971 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25972 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25973 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25974 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25975 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25976 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25977 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25978 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25979 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25980 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25981 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25982 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25983 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25984 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25985 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25986 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25987 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25988 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25989 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25990 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25991 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25992 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25993 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25994 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25995 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25996 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25997 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25998 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─25999 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26000 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26001 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26002 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26003 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26004 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26005 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26006 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26007 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26008 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26014 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26015 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26030 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26035 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26037 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26038 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26039 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26040 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26044 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26045 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26048 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26049 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26051 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26052 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26054 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26055 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26056 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26057 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26059 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26062 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26063 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26064 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26065 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26066 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26068 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26069 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26070 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26071 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26074 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26075 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26076 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26078 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26080 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26081 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26083 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26084 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26086 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26088 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           ├─26090 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini
           └─26091 /some/nfs/share/production/bin/uwsgi --ini production.ini

Jul 05 12:14:29 backend uwsgi[25432]: *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.16 (64bit) on [Thu Jul  5 12:14:29 2018] ***
Jul 05 12:14:29 backend uwsgi[25432]: compiled with version: 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) on 12 February 2018 22:16:17
Jul 05 12:14:29 backend uwsgi[25432]: os: Linux-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 9 14:09:15 UTC 2015
Jul 05 12:14:29 backend uwsgi[25432]: nodename: backend
Jul 05 12:14:29 backend uwsgi[25432]: machine: x86_64
Jul 05 12:14:29 backend uwsgi[25432]: clock source: unix
Jul 05 12:14:29 backend uwsgi[25432]: pcre jit disabled
Jul 05 12:14:29 backend uwsgi[25432]: detected number of CPU cores: 4
Jul 05 12:14:29 backend uwsgi[25432]: current working directory: /some/nfs/share/production/bin/workers/uwsgi
Jul 05 12:14:29 backend uwsgi[25432]: writing pidfile to /some/nfs/share/production/bin/workers/uwsgi/production.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

If you are running uWSGI through systemctl, including the emperor file using the `--ini` directive will be interpreted as the ini actually being a service. The correct way of putting the command in `ExecStart` is:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${UWSGI_BIN} --emperor ${UWSGI_INI}'
```

where `UWSGI_BIN` is the location of the binary and `UWSGI_INI` is the location where the `.ini` files representing services are.

I figured that if I want to set any emperor configuration flags, these should go in the `ExecStart`. It's a bit unfortunate but apparently this is how it is.